# The linear projection of projective spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:X=\mathbb{P}_n\smallsetminus p\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{n-1}$ be the linear projection. What is the cokernel of the morphism 
$$  0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{n-1}}\rightarrow \pi_*(\mathcal{O}_X)? $$

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is the total space of line bundle $O(1)$ on $P^{n-1}$. Consequently, 
$$
\pi_*(O_X) = O \oplus O(-1) \oplus O(-2) \oplus \dots
$$
and the cokernel is $\oplus_{i\ge 1} O(-i)$.

Comment: That would give a lot of functions on $\Bbb{P}^n\smallsetminus p$ ...

Comment: @abx: of course the sign was wrong, now it is corrected, thanks!